# Naturality of Lie bracket — alternate proof

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds, and let $F: M \to N$ be a smooth map. Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields on $M$, and let $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ be vector fields on $N$. We say that $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ are $F$-related if $dF_p(X_p) = \tilde{X}_{F(p)}$ for every $p \in M$. There is a theorem (naturality of the Lie bracket):

> If $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ are $F$-related and $Y$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are $F$-related, then $[X,Y]$ and $[\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y}]$ are $F$-related.

A very concise proof is as follows:

Let $f \in C^\infty(N)$. We only need to show that $[X,Y](f \circ F) = [\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y}]f$, which is
$$(XY - YX)(f \circ F) = (\tilde{X}\tilde{Y} - \tilde{Y}\tilde{X})f.$$
This equality follows from $XY(f \circ F) = X(\tilde{Y}f \circ F) = \tilde{X}\tilde{Y}f$.

**My question is, how can we prove this theorem without introducing the smooth function $f$?**

When $F$ is a local diffeomorphism, we can prove the theorem directly using coordinates. Let the matrix $(b^i_j) = (\partial_jF^i)$ with inverse $(a^i_j)$. We compute:
\begin{align*}
\tilde{x}^j \tilde{\partial}_j \tilde{y}^i - \tilde{y}^j \tilde{\partial}_j \tilde{x}^i &= b^j_k x^k a^l_j \partial_l(b^i_my^m) - b^j_k y^k a^l_j \partial_l(b^i_mx^m)\\
&= x^l\partial_l(b^i_my^m) - y^l\partial_l(b^i_mx^m)\\
&= b^i_m(x^l \partial_ly^m - y^l \partial_lx^m) + \partial_l\partial_mF^i(x^ly^m - x^my^l)\\
&= b^i_m(x^l \partial_ly^m - y^l \partial_lx^m).
\end{align*}

This proof is also in the accepted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/377252) of this MSE question: [Pushforward of Lie Bracket](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365535/pushforward-of-lie-bracket).

However, when $F$ is **not locally invertible**, then the matrix $(b^i_j)$ won't be invertible either. The matrix $(a^i_j)$ in the proof above would be undefined! This situation seems very strange. It appears that the only way to prove this theorem is to use the abstract definition of $[X,Y]f = (XY - YX)f$. The coordinate expression $[X,Y] = (x^j \partial_j y^i - y^j \partial_j x^i)$ seems inadequate.

Another abstract definition of $[X,Y]$ is the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_XY$, which is computed using the flow map of $X$. We can also discuss the naturality of the Lie derivative: are $\mathcal{L}_XY$ and $\mathcal{L}_{\tilde{X}}\tilde{Y}$ $F$-related? If $F$ is not locally invertible, then it seems we can't prove this **only using the abstract notion of Lie derivative** either. We have to use the fact that $\mathcal{L}_XY = [X,Y]$ and return to the Lie bracket case. This also feels strange because the definition $[X,Y]f = (XY - YX)f$ is so special here.

I also discussed the question in this article on Banana Space (a Chinese website dedicated to sharing math): [Intuitive interpretation of Lie bracket](https://www.bananaspace.org/wiki/%E7%94%A8%E6%88%B7:ZhangYH/Lie_%E6%8B%AC%E5%8F%B7%E7%9A%84%E5%B7%AE%E5%88%86%E7%9B%B4%E8%A7%82). However, it is written in Chinese.

**Update:** I seem to find a way to prove $\mathcal{L}_XY$ and $\mathcal{L}_{\tilde{X}}\tilde{Y}$ are $F$-related only using the abstract notion of Lie derivative. I have written an anwser.

Comment: A generalization of this is stated and proved here: https://deaneyang.github.io//blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2021/04/01/PullbackConnection.html

Comment: Since accepted answers can change, it is better to link to a specific answer.  I have done so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My favorite proof of this takes a step back.

If $M$ is a manifold, let $TM$ be its tangent bundle.  The total space is itself a manifold, so you can form the tangent bundle of $TM$, i.e.

$$T(TM) = T^2 M.$$

The Clairaut theorem about mixed partial derivatives being equal tells you that there is an involution of $T^2 M$,

$$\iota_M : T^2 M \to T^2 M.$$

If you write $TM$ as the set of all pairs

$$TM = \{(p,v) : p \in M, v \in T_p M\}$$

then

$$\iota_M(p,v,w,y) = (p,w,v,y).$$

From this your Lie bracket of vector fields could be described this way.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields, then they have the form

$$X,Y : M \to TM.$$

So you can form the directional derivatives

$$TX \circ Y : M \to T^2 M,\hskip 1cm  TY \circ X : M \to T^2 M$$

$TX$ denotes the induced map of tangent bundles, i.e. the bundle-theoretic derivative. $TX(p,v) = (X(p), DX_p(v))$.

Now observe that $TX \circ Y - \iota_M \circ TY \circ X$ is not only well-defined but it takes values in $ker(T\pi : T^2 M \to TM)$, where $\pi : TM \to M$ is the tangent bundle projection map, $\pi(p,v) = p$.  $T\pi$ evaluates as $T\pi(p,v,w,y) = (p,w)$, thus the kernel are elements in $T^2 M$ of the form $(p,v,0,y)$, i.e. $y \in T_p M$ thus the fibers are canonically identified with $T_p M$, so via this identification we have

$$TX \circ Y - \iota_M \circ TY \circ X : M \to TM$$

and this is the Lie bracket of $X$ and $Y$.

Your result then just pops out of the above.

Comment: Since MO doesn't allow emoji reacts, I have to type some characters first. 

Comment: Thank you so much! I  How can we prove this vector field is exactly $[X,Y]$ in a coordinate-free way? And, which books can I read to learn more about the structure of $T^2M$?

Answer (score 5):

The Lie bracket can somehow be computed from flows, and the flows intertwine. In more detail, if $X$ maps to $\bar{X}$, i.e. $F'(p)X(p)=\bar{X}(F(p))$ then clearly the flows of $X$ and $\bar{X}$ intertwine: just look at the differential equations of the flows. But then the Lie bracket is computed by *switchbacks* of flows:
$$
[X,Y]:=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}e^{-\sqrt{t}Y}e^{-\sqrt{t}X}e^{\sqrt{t}Y}e^{\sqrt{t}X}.
$$

Comment: Are the square-roots necessary here?

Comment: I would say that the square roots are needed. Consider the special case where $X$ and $Y$ are left invariant vector fields on a Lie group, say on the general linear group to be both specific and also very general (by Ado's theorem). Plug in to the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula to see the relevant cancellations and the factors of $t$ in the remaining terms. If we replace $\sqrt{t}$ by $t$, the $[X,Y]$ arises in the $t^2$ term. But acceleration is a messy business on manifolds. (See Ryan Budney's answer for an excellent description of acceleration.)

Answer (score 3):

Here I present a proof of the naturality of Lie derivative, only using the abstract definition, and without referencing the naturality of Lie bracket.

Let $\phi(t,p)=\phi^t(p)$ be the flow generated by $X$, and
$\psi(t,p)=\psi^t(p)$ be the flow generated by $\tilde X$.

Note that $\psi(\cdot,F(p))$ and $F\circ\phi(\cdot,p)$ are
both integral curves of $Y$ started from $F(p)$. From the uniqueness of integral curve, we deduce $F \circ \phi^t =\psi^t \circ F$. As a consequence, $$dF_{\phi^t(p)} \phi^t_* = \psi^t_* dF_p,$$
so
$$(\psi^t_*)^{-1}dF_{\phi^t(p)}=dF_p(\phi^t_*)^{-1}.$$
Now we see

$$dF_p\mathcal  L_XY
=\frac d {dt} dF_p(\phi^t_*)^{-1}Y_{\phi^t(p)}
=\frac d {dt} (\psi^t_*)^{-1}dF_{\phi^t(p)}Y_{\phi^t(p)}
=\frac d {dt} (\psi^t_*)^{-1}\tilde Y_{\psi^t(F(p))}
=\mathcal L_{\tilde X} \tilde Y.$$

This proof does not require $F$ to be a local diffeomorphism.